# access SparkContext from rJava call

Tags: r, rjava, sparkr

the SparkContext in SparkR (v1.5.1) is a

```
Java ref type org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext
```

however when creating my class:

```
.jnew("com.example.MyClass","sc")
```

for my scala class: class TableReader(sc: JavaSparkContext), I'm getting a: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

What is this "Java ref type" and how can I get the actual context from it to send through rJava?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SparkR seems to have its own Java interoperability implemented in [backend.R](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/R/pkg/R/backend.R). Calls are made in the form `SparkR:::newJObject(className, args)`, though I can't find any specific documentation, other than in tests in the same project.

sqlContext needs to be initialized and relevant jars loaded during startup using --jars {csv jars} or --packages as noted in the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sparkr.html#from-data-sources).